# Quantum Hall Effect, Shubnikov de Haas oscillations

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

I have done a measurement at a HgTe 2DEG. I have measured nice plateaus in Rxy and Shubnikov de Haas Oscillations in Rxx. 
In the  B field range between 1 and 3 Tesla I see some variation in the Shubnikov de Haas oscillations compared to bigger magnetic fields. One minimum is not so deep and the next is deeper then the next one is less deep the next one deeper again. 
What is the reason for this?[image]

Comment: Could it be the result of more than one characteristic frequency present in the data? Have you tried doing a Fourier transform of your data to see what it looks like in frequency space?